# HttpServerRequest: request is handled several times

Tags: java, httprequest, vert.x

I wrote the following code:

```
public static void handleRequest(HttpServerRequest request, Vertx vertx) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (request.method() == HttpMethod.GET) {
            if (request.path().equals("/healthcheck")) {
                returnResponse(request, "I'm alive!!!\n", true);
                System.out.println("OK");
                return;
            }
            ...

        }
        returnResponse(request, "Not Valid Request", false);
        System.out.println("This request cannot be handled");
    }
```

The weird part is that once I get a GET request with path "/healthcheck", I get in console both:

> OK

and

> This request cannot be handled

I'd expect to get only "OK", and then the method has to return. 
Do you know how to make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be getting more than one request and one of them is not a get request. Can you monitor the server by inserting Log Statements

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that my browser does send two requests.
The first request is the  GET localhost:8080/healthcheck and the second one is GET localhost:8080/favicon.

GET localhost:8080/favicon doesn't satisfy the condition, and the code prints "This request cannot be handled".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to handle a Preflighted request.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control)

> Preflighted requests unlike simple requests (discussed above),
>   "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP OPTIONS request header to
>   the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the
>   actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted
>   like this since they may have implications to user data

try this instead

```
public static void handleRequest(HttpServerRequest request, Vertx vertx) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if(request.method() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
            return;
        } 

        if (request.method() == HttpMethod.GET) {
            if (request.path().equals("/healthcheck")) {
                returnResponse(request, "I'm alive!!!\n", true);
                System.out.println("OK");
                return;
            }
            ...

        }
        returnResponse(request, "Not Valid Request", false);
        System.out.println("This request cannot be handled");
    }
```